# Detecting "Activate right-to-left paragraph direction" in winforms

Tags: winforms, globalization

I have RightToLeft issues.

So there is a property Control.RightToLeft that I can get and set and behaves consistently.

Windows has a keyboard shortcut [Activate right-to-left paragraph direction](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/word-help/keyboard-shortcuts-for-right-to-left-formatting-HP005258095.aspx) (sorry that's the best link I have found so far). This seems to do the same/very similar thing but does not set Control.RightToLeft.

Does anyone know what is going on here?

I'm guessing that the keyboard shortcut is doing something in the unmanaged world and the relevant .net change handlers are not being tickled.

Note at least one right to left keyboard must be installed for it to work.

After Hans commented on the influence of Office I did another test:
I cloned a Win 7 Enterprise vm that is fairly clean (it does not have Office installed). I added the Hebrew (keyboard) under "Text Services and Input Languages". I created a .Net 3.5 winforms application and added a TextBox.

I can confirm - Right Shift + Right Control does shift text to the right.

Comment: That shortcut keystroke is highly specific to Office programs.  It is not a Windows feature nor can you expect a Winforms program to handle it automatically.  Or any GUI class library for that matter.

Comment: Hi Hans. Notepad responds to the keystroke as does a test winforms application I created (a TextBox on a Form will suffice).